# How do I use matrix math to solve a scheduling problem?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matrix

I'm seeking recommendations on pythons packages that can help generate new matrices based on constraints.

I've built a schedule, the columns are time slots and the rows are people. Each row is a person's schedule. If 1, then she is working. If 0 she is not working.

```
Today's Schedule:
   12-1  1-2  2-3  3-4  4-5
0     1    1    1    1    1
1     1    1    1    1    1
2     1    1    1    1    0
3     1    1    1    1    0
```

I also have a list of positions that need to be filled in each time slot. Anybody can work any position. The corresponding value is the number of people needed.

```
            12-1  1-2  2-3  3-4  4-5
position_1     0    1    1    0    0
position_2     1    2    2    1    1
position_3     1    1    1    2    1
```

I'm looking for a program that allows me to assign positions to people for each hour they are working. There are of course multiple options. Are there any packages that handle this type of problem? Essentially every value the schedule matrix can be position 1, 2 or 3 with the condition that the total for that timeslot = the total in the positions matrix. Extra people can be assigned to an extra position, not listed.

Comment: The problem you describe sounds like the assignment problem. There are various ways to solve it. You could use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html, or you could look into metaheuristics (for ex: https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/overview). This is only the tip of the iceberg, but hope it helps.

Comment: it is actually an operations problem for work. this is helpful! i came across pulp and have been using it

Comment: Yeah, I know - it is a scheduling problem. The one you described sounds like a certain type of scheduling problem called the assignment problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem .